# How do I set DML Options when using the REST API?

Tags: apex, rest-api, soap-api, case, configuration

My question is *nearly* identical to an [existing question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/19317/customer-portal-new-case-comment-notification-not-working).  To summarize the problem, my case owners aren't receiving an e-mail notification when a new comment is added to their cases.  Please view the linked question for the pretty pictures which further describe the issue.

However, the difference between our questions is that I'm creating a case via the REST API (not SOAP).  How do I set these magical DML Options?  Is it even possible, or are users stuck with one of three workarounds (that I can think of):

1. Create a workflow e-mail alert (I would vote for this option)
2. Write an Apex Trigger that hooks into the insert
3. Use the SOAP API and set the option (not practical if already using the REST API)

Comment: I dont know whether its possible to set DML options in REST but one way i would solve is use apex trigger and set the DML options in triggers .The data from REST will go through this trigger .Hope this trick is worth trying

Comment: @MohithShrivastava do you have to do it on an update or can you set dml options in a before trigger?

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F00000008wj7IAA

It has to be after trigger

Comment: @Justin Just wondering how you solved this issue. Care to share please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating my own workflow rule to e-mail the case owner (option #1 in my original question).

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried using the [SForce-Auto-Assign](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/headers_autoassign.htm) Assignment Rule Header?

> The Assignment Rule header is a request header applied when creating or updating Cases or Leads. If enabled, the active assignment rules are used. If disabled, the active assignment rules are not applied. If a valid AssignmentRule ID is provided, the AssignmentRule is applied. If the header is not provided with a request, REST API defaults to using the active assignment rules.

There doesn't appear to be an equavalent emailHeader. So this probably won't be sufficient.

---

Another possible work around - You could use Apex to implement your own REST API that already includes the required DMLOptions.

E.g.

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/Case/*')
global with sharing class CaseRestResource {


  @HttpPost
    global static String doPost(String subject) {
        Case newCase = new Case();

        newCase.Subject = subject;
        // Set AccountID, etc...

        Database.DMLOptions dmo = new Database.DMLOptions();
        dmo.emailHeader.triggerUserEmail = true;
        dmo.assignmentRuleHeader.useDefaultRule = true;
        newCase.setOptions(dmo);

        insert newCase;
        return newCase.Id;
    }
}
```

Comment: While the custom API endpoint is an interesting idea (+1 for that!) if I went down that path I feel like I might as well just write a trigger to handle it as opposed to changing my code to point to a non-standard REST API resource.

Comment: OK. No problem. Either you or @MohithShrivastav could post that as the actual answer if you like.

Comment: I'm going to give it a few more days to see if any other answers happen to trickle in.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: The `SForce-Auto-Assign` Assignment Rule Header worked for me, thanks. I corrected the broken docs link.