# case assignment rule is getting fired when case comment is added from API

Tags: rest-api, integration, case, servicecloud, assignment-rules

We have setup assignment rules and also setup default case owner from support settings. We are adding case comments through REST API call from external system and whenever case comment is added, it is resetting the case owner of the case by firing the assignment rules.

If an agent has aready taken ownership of the case , when comment is added that ownership goes back to the queue as per the assignment rules and it is not helpful.

I learnt that whenever API call takes place it fires assignment rules thats how salesforce works. So,

1. first workaround we tried creating a checkbox, setting it to false by default and adding condition in the assignment rule saying run the rules only when checkbox is false. And we are sending the checkbox vale as true ONLY when comment is added from the API so that way assignment rules won't work.
   --> It did not work, although the value is coming as true, assignment rules still fires (As per sfdc standard behaviour) and it doesnt meet any of the rule criteria so it assigns default case owner defined in support settings.
2. second workaround we tried is uisng the trigger before inserting the case comment and setting the rule to false using below code.
   after activating the trigger, and testing the scenario.. the owner is still getting replaced when comment is added. Any suggestion would be of GREAT HELP!!

   ```
   trigger test on CaseComment (before insert)
   {

           List<CaseComment> cc = new list<CaseComment>();

           for (CaseComment cd : Trigger.new) {
                   Database.DMLOptions dmo = new Database.DMLOptions();
                   dmo.assignmentRuleHeader.useDefaultRule = false;
                   cd.setoptions(dmo);
                  cc.add(cd);
           }

           insert cc;
   }
   ```

Thanks!!

Comment: What does the REST API do? Is it using the SFDC REST API and directly inserting CaseComment? Or is it calling a custom Apex Rest service that converts the REST POST to an `insert thecaseComment` DML call?  I'm not sure why you have a trigger at all; and you shouldnt be doing DML on the triggered list itself in a before Insert trigger

Comment: We are using REST API to insert comment, trigger was just a way to stop assignment rule from firing, it is not working anyway.

Comment: I believe the answer was addressed here:  http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/48202/2602 with reference to https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/headers_autoassign.htm